# Creating Delegates of an unavailable return type

Tags: c#

Assume we have a static method "Instance" in a type: "SomeType"

`MethodInfo instanceMethod = SomeType.GetMethod("Instance");`

The method returns an object of a type that is not available in my code as it does not reference the assembly where that class is defined.

I would like then, to cast it to "object"

Like this:

`Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object>), null, "Instance")`

However I get this exception:
`System.ArgumentException: Error binding to target method.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Delegate.CreateDelegate.aspx) overload that you [appear to be using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12f294ye.aspx) only works for instance methods, not static ones. If you pass the `MethodInfo` instead of the name `"Instance"`, you'll be using [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551.aspx) that will work.

Also, `Func<object>` isn't compatible with just any type. You can create a `Func<>` that matches the method's return type with [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx).

```
Type funcType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(instanceMethod.ReturnType);
Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(funcType, null, instanceMethod);
```

As an aside, I'd name the method `GetInstance` instead of `Instance`, to make things clearer. (if it were a property, `Instance` would be appropriate)